# How to escape the unescaped quotes in a csv file string using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have received a file (size > 1GB) which is CSV, separated by `|`
When I was importing it to bigquery we found out there are some unescaped `"` in the file.
How can I fix the file by using `sed` command

```
This|is|test only|to check quotes||123|""
second|line|"with quotes"|no text|""|345|""
third line|with|"start quote" and another " "|a word after quotes|" "|677|""
```

expected (no change in line 1,2)

```
This|is|test only|to check quotes||123|""
second|line|"with quotes"|no text|""| 345|""
third line|with|"start quote"" and another "" "|a word after quotes|" "|677|""
```

My idea is if there is a `"` that doesn't start or ends with `|` should be replaced with `""`

Comment: Your expected output does not seem to make sense. I would expect `"""start quote"" and another "" """`

Answer (score 2):

With Perl and lookarounds:

```bash
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(?<![|"])"(?![|"])(?!$)/""/g' ip.csv
This|is|test only|to check quotes||123|""
second|line|"with quotes"|no text|""|345|""
third line|with|"start quote"" and another "" "|a word after quotes|" "|677|""
```

`(?<![|"])` and `(?![|"])` are negative lookarounds, helps here to match `"` only if there's no `"` or `|` characters to the left/right.

`(?<!^)` and `(?!$)` are there to prevent matching a `"` at the start/end of lines (since `|` won't be present at the start of the first field or the end of the last field.

Use `perl -i` for inplace editing.

Comment: It works except it also converts `This|""` to `This|"""` which makes the file corrupted

Comment: As a workaround changed it to `perl -i -pe 's/(?<!\|)"(?!\|)/""/g;s/"""/""/g' data.txt`

Comment: I'd suggest to add more such corner cases to the question. For ex, what is expected output if field content is `apple""123`? For workaround, use `["|]` instead of `\|` in the lookarounds.

Answer (score 2):

As a nice `perl` solution has been provided, here is a `sed` alternative:

```
sed -E 's/([^|"])"([^|"])/\1""\2/g' file
```

The regex `[^|"]` matches any characters other than `|` and `"`.
If a double quote is surrounded by the characters above, replace
it with `""`.

Comment: Good one, assuming something like `apple""123` isn't a possible field content and OP wants them to be changed to `apple""""123`

Comment: @Sundeep oh, that's right. Thank you for the comment. Let me sleep over it :)

Comment: Looks like not changing `""` is what OP wanted anyway...

Comment: @Sundeep thank you for the comment. Then I'd leave my answer as is :).
Actually changing the multiple double quotes in the middle of fields is a good
example to show the usefulness of lookaround assertions and it will not be easy
to implement the equivalent operation without using them. Cheers.